# Does magento store price before special price in database?

Tags: product, price

I am working on magento store. I need to extract the price for the specific product for every transaction included the price before special price being applied.

**Would like to know if magento store the data or no.**

Comment: you want to show 2 prices from frontend or what do you want to do with 2 prices? They were also input from backend.

Answer (score 2):

`$product->getData('price')` will return the raw value of the product's price field
`$product->getPrice()` will return the product's price, as it it stored for the  type of the product (simple, configurable etc.)
`$product->getSpecialPrice()` will return the product's special price field, the value from the db
`$product->getFinalPrice()` will return the selling price of the product, taxing into consideration active special prices, catalog price rules, taxes etc.

As far as I could tell, you're looking for is one of `$product->getData('price')` or `$product->getPrice()`.